# prevent hammering/script parsers

Tags: apache-2.2

how can you prevent that scripts can parese the server for paths and dirs?

from error.log in Apache:

```
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:13 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/scripts
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:13 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/admin
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:13 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/admin
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:13 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/admin
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:13 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/db
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:13 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/dbadmin
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:13 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/myadmin
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:13 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/mysql
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:13 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/mysqladmin
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:14 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/typo3
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:14 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/phpadmin
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:15 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/phpMyAdmin
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:15 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/scripts
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:15 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmyadmin1
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:15 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmyadmin2
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:15 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/pma
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:15 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/web
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:15 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/xampp
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:18 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/php-my-admin
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:18 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/websql
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:18 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/scripts
[Thu Jul 07 11:28:18 2011] [error] [client 91.121.134.32] File does not exist: /var/www/phpMyAdmin
```

Answer (score 2):

If your host is linux and you can install software then try [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/). Both should be available in your distibution's repos.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/), or you could write your own custom access rules

Comment: how could you write access rules on this subject?

Comment: At a very basic level, if your website did not use php / support any files with a .php extension you could have a rewrite rule for that.

Comment: but how can you make a rewrite rule which looks at hosts who get alot of "file not found" errors?

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: or how can you rewrite all 404 to an error page... eg error.php

Comment: You do that with ErrorDocument in Apache conf

Comment: isn't it possible to do it with a rewrite rule so you'll keep the requested page and not redirected to eg. error.php every time